# Unresolved reference for Modifier.preferredSize and Modifier.prefferredHeight

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am following this [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7yY2OocGiQU) Tutorial where they are using `Modifier.preferredSize()` on a box and `Modifier.preferredHeight()` on a Spacer Composable - all other chained Modifiers are fine.

However Android Studio is not recognizing these 2 options.

Here is the code that I am working with:

```
Column() {
        var isBlue by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
        val color = if(isBlue) Color.Blue else Color.Green

        Button(onClick = { isBlue = !isBlue }) {}


        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.preferredHeight(128.dp))
        Box(modifier = Modifier.preferredHeight(128.dp).background(color = color)){}
    }
```

The Editor is high-lighting **`preferredHeight`** as unresolved.

This is the image from the IDE for perspective.

[image]

I am using `compose_version = '1.0.1'` and I'm on AS Arctic Fox

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`preferredSize` was renamed to `size` and `preferredHeight` to `height`

If I face some old video/article with invalid api, I'm searching through [compose-samples](https://github.com/android/compose-samples)(official samples from the maintainers) commits to find place where this method was deprecated/renamed, it's the easiest way to know if it just was renamed or I need to change more logic. In this case change was on [this](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/commit/284bf9e4b15f3db35dda75ae6b68e17b4baf3da8#) commit

Comment: This could have been a comment followed by a vote to close. 50k users should not be answering questions with screenshots of code in them.

Comment: @miken32 the question can be found on search engines, it was found by people who needed it, and it helped them. The image is not a valuable part of the question: it is perfectly clear what the author's problem is, even if you remove the image. p.s. I didn't have 50k at the time I answered, but I don't see why we should remove it now.

Answer (score 5):

`Modifier.preferredWidth/preferredHeight/preferredSize` were renamed to `width/height/size` starting from [`1.0.0-beta01`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-foundation#1.0.0-beta01)

Answer (score -3):

I resolved it by following the mouse over suggestion, pressing the alt+Enter to import automatically the required referenced packages
I am following the lessons for andoid and kotlin and had stacked with this error.